# Find all the words in a file that contain all four lower-case letters “inux” in order

Tags: grep

The four letters should be in alphabetical order.
For example, `inux` and `ianauax` are in the output, but `ixnux` and `naiauax` are not.

**I can only use `grep`  to accomplish this task.**

I tried `grep 'i\w*n\w*u\w*x\w*'` but i failed because `ixnux` is in the output but it shouldn't be in the output (`ixnux` is not a word which 'i','n','u','x' are in alphabet order)

Comment: I wonder if there's some practical application to this, or if this is homework? What about the other letters in between, must they also be in alphabetical order? I.e., is `isnux` ok?

Comment: antineurotoxin
Cristineaux
fricandeaux
influx
influxable
influxes
influxible
influxibly
influxion
influxionism
influxious
influxive
interflux

guys...how to make sure all the letters after 'X' are not 'i' 'n' and 'u'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another `grep` approach.

```
grep '[^nux]*i[^iux]*n[^inx]*u[^unu]*x' infile
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this way but I use [!] in the wildcard and I was wrong :(

Comment: @αғsнιη, nope, try this `grep '[^nux]*i[^iux]*n[^inx]*u[^unu]*x' <<<"###i  n\t u--x  aaa"` - no words here

Comment: @Ulysses in regular expression `^` means _all but not including these_

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, but then I doubt for [this OP's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420934/find-all-the-words-in-a-file-that-contain-all-four-lower-case-letters-inux-in#comment756880_420935)!

Comment: yeah I finally understand it. Thanks. And then I add [^inux] right after *x because if not, then influxible is still in the output lol. Thanks so much

Comment: @Ulysses, `[!abc]` is the original shell glob notation for "any character except these". in regex it's `[^abc]` and I think most shells support the latter for globs, too

Answer (score 0):

**`grep`** solution:

```
s="inux and ianauax are in the output, but ixnux and naiauax are not."
grep -o '\b[a-h0-9_]*i[a-l0-9_]*n[a-t0-9_]*u[a-y0-9_]*x\w*\b' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
inux
ianauax
```

Comment: The Wisdom! You the best!

Comment: in the wildcard, can I just say '\b[!nux]*i[!iux]*n[!inx]*u[!inu]*x\w*\b'  ?because the word might contains some symbols

Comment: @Ulysses, the **"word"** here is `[a-Z0-9_]` chars only

Comment: What about `inuxi`?

Comment: @tomasz, what wrong with it? nothing special

Comment: That depends on the interpretation of the task. `i` appears two times, so is this to be filtered out or not?

Comment: @tomasz, you may ask the OP if you really want

Comment: @Ulysses As above.